# A Free MIB Builder/Compiler

Tags: networking, snmp, mib

I have to changes some old MIB Files, I did it in notepad++, loaded in iReasoning but after loading in MG MIB soft trial - there were a lot of errors.
Can somebody recommend some free MIB (OID) Builder and Compiler?
Need for Windows.

Comment: There are many command line compilers that are free out there, such as mib2c from Net-SNMP. If you want an IDE style compiler/builder, all you get is the commercial ones.

Comment: @LexLi, some examples?

Comment: http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/mib2c.html is the man page for mib2c, and the Windows build of Net-SNMP can be found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp%20binaries/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used LibSmi project.
It compile and shows respective errors, warnings, etc.
http://www.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/projects/libsmi/tools/?lang=de